# Как сделать правильный поворот объекта?

Tags: python, pygame

Я хотел сделать небольшую демку на pygame. В моей демке есть летящие ножи, при нажатии на клавишу b, они появляются.

```
def knife(list, key):
    surf = pygame.image.load("knife.png")
    surf = pygame.transform.scale(surf, (80, 20))    
    rect = surf.get_rect(bottomright=(list, 630))
    if knifeRotate == "left":
        surf = pygame.transform.flip(surf, True, False)
    sc.blit(surf, rect)


if keys[pygame.K_b] and (xKnife < 1280 or xKnife > 0):
    knife = True            

if knife == True:
    Diego.knife(xKnife, keys) 
if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and not keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    x += speed
    sprite += 1
    knifeRotate = "right"
elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and not keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    x -= speed
    sprite += 1 
    knifeRotate = "left"    
else:
    sprite = 0
```

Мне нужно чтобы при их вызове они летели в одну сторону, но если нож не исчез и ходишь влево или вправо, он изменяет траекторию своего полёта.

Как это исправить?

Если я дал недостаточно информации, напишите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# прежде всего нужно убедится что переменная будет меняться
knife = keys[pygame.K_b] and (xKnife < 1280 or xKnife > 0)
 
if knife == True: # это условие должно быть общим мне кажется
    Diego.knife(xKnife, keys) 
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and not keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x += speed
        sprite += 1
        knifeRotate = "right"
    elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and not keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x -= speed
        sprite += 1 
        knifeRotate = "left"    
    else:
        sprite = 0
```